# Triangle shaped progress bar in xml (android)

Tags: android, progress-bar

So, I am trying to create a triangle shaped progress bar.

I need this in order to show the intensity, therefor ,when the intensity is low, the progress is down where the triangle shape is thin, if the intensity is high, the progress go up, where the triangle is thicker.

So, to be even more specific, what I can't seem to handle ,is the progress.I cannot manage to make it triangle shaped and use it with a triangle background resource.

I don't really have any code to publish ,since I didn't find anything to help me even get started.